# Extended LinearLayout not rotating

Tags: android, layout, rotation

I'm trying to create a custom `LinearLayout` that can rotate all children in the layout by a set angle. That is, I want to rotate the entire canvas **and** the children, not the children individually.

I need to support `API Level 10`, so `android:rotate` which was introduced in `API Level 11` will not help me here.

I've been looking around and think I need to do something along the lines of this code below, but with this code nothing gets rotated.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

```
public class RotationLayout extends LinearLayout {    

public RotationLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public RotationLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public RotationLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}
private void init() {
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(350,0,0);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
}`
```

Comment: You are calling `canvas.restore()`? Wouldn't that undo what `canvas.rotate()` did?

Comment: override draw(Canvas) instead of onDraw(Canvas)

Comment: Tried both your suggestions, no luck :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with a few changes.

In the onCreate(Bundle) of an activity class, I initialized the RotationLayout:

```
RotationLayout rl = new RotationLayout(this);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.some_drawable));

rl.addView(iv);

setContentView(rl);
```

And the view was indeed rotated 350 degrees(or 10 degrees counter-clockwise) around (0,0). This was what I changed:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.rotate(350,0,0);
}
```

From notes on `Canvas.save()` [(Link)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#save%28%29):

> Saves the current matrix and clip onto a private stack. Subsequent
>   calls to translate,scale,rotate,skew,concat or clipRect,clipPath will
>   all operate as usual, but when the balancing call to restore() is
>   made, those calls will be forgotten, and the settings that existed
>   before the save() will be reinstated.

Comment: Thanks alot for you time vikram, this does exactly what I needed!